# SQL - Finding the maximum date group by id table

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

Having a table below, I need to get rows with the maximum date having statut equal 2

```
REMUN_ID    HISTO_ID   DATE_MAJ                 STATUT
2122        7005       08/27/2014 11:10:23        2
1603        5486       08/27/2014 11:10:21        1
2122        5151       08/27/2014 11:08:36        1
1603        4710       08/27/2014 11:08:32        2
```

I need to get the row with the maximum date and group by REMUN_ID
the result using this request

```sql
select remun_id, max(date_maj)
from histo_statut_remun 
group by remun_id;
```

Result :

```
REMUN_ID      DATE_MAJ                 
2122        08/27/2014 11:10:23        
1603        08/27/2014 11:10:21
```

I need to adjust the request to get only rows with statut = 2 from this result

My purpose is to get the result below, a subquery of the first one to get only those with statut 2.

```
REMUN_ID    DATE_MAJ                 
2122        08/27/2014 11:10:23
```

PS : if i used the clause where i will get these results :

```
REMUN_ID     DATE_MAJ                 
2122        08/27/2014 11:10:23        
1603        08/27/2014 11:08:32
```

and that's not what i want to get.

Any suggestions? 
Thank you

Comment: SQL-Server, Oracle, Postgres, MySQL, DB2, SQLite, what? What are you using?

Comment: add a `HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN statut=2 THEN 1 END)>0` after GROUP BY

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select remun_id, date_maj
from (
  select r.*, 
         max(date_maj) over (partition by REMUN_ID) as max_date
  from histo_statut_remun r
) 
where date_maj = max_date
  and statut = 2;
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7eb75/1

Comment: I think it is not safe to use `MAX(date)` here if you want to guaranty single row per group, using `ROW_NUMBER()` is better, see here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25774658/sql-join-to-correlated-subquery-where-tables-are-related-by-overlapping-ranges/25775149?noredirect=1#comment40310388_25775149

Comment: @Bulat: that all depends if hb.sara wants to see multiple rows if the same `remun_id` has more than one date is equal to the highest.